# Trying to return value from ref.on() in factory to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I'm trying to retrieve the value from a Firebase query in a factory to my controller but no success. Anyone have an idea??

Controller:

```
main.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope, totalusers){
  $scope.city = "whatever";
  $scope.total = totalusers.getusers($scope.city);
});
```

Factory (where I have the query to retrieve how many users have the Name specified):

```
app.factory("totalusers", function(FURL) {
    var gettotalusers      = {};
    gettotalusers.getusers = function(city) {
        var tusers = new Firebase(FURL + "/Users/" + city);
        var count  = 0;

        tusers.on("value", function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
                if (child.val().Name != undefined) {
                    count++;
                }
            });
            var total = count;
            return total;
        });

    }
    return gettotalusers;
});
```

Any clue would be great, thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the firebase value is done asynchronously, so that the count value is still 0 when it is assigned to the `total` which is then immediately returned. You could use the `$q` service to create a promise and resolve it when the firebase callback returned

```
app.factory("totalusers", function(FURL, $q){
  var gettotalusers = {};
  gettotalusers.getusers = function(city){
    var tusers = new Firebase(FURL + "/Users/" + city);
    var count = 0;
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    tusers.on("value", function(snapshot){
      snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        if(child.val().Name != undefined){
          count++;
        }
      });
      deferred.resolve(count);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
  return gettotalusers;
});
```

Then in your controller, you cannot assign the result directly. You need to do that in a promise handler method like so:

```
main.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope, totalusers){
  $scope.city = "whatever";
  totalusers.getusers($scope.city).then(
    function(total) {
      $scope.total = total;
    },
    function(err) {
      // handle error
    }
  );
});
```

For more details, see the $q docs and read about the concept of promises. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

You could also try to write your count in a more functional way using filter and reduce:

```
var total = snapshot
  .filter(function(item) { return child.val().Name !== undefined })
  .reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    return acc + curr;
  }
);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. It worked really well. I dont know about filter and reduce but I'm gonna take a look and check. If you have an example about it would be cool. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I have no experience with the firebase api, so please consider the answer of @Anid Monsur for his explanations and use the promise returned by the firebase api. If you want to learn more about the array functions, I think the mozilla docs are a great resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 2):

Using `ref.on()` in this scenario is a bad idea because it will continue to sync that node even after the function has finished. You should call `ref.off()`, or more simply, use `ref.once()`. If you're using the latest version of Firebase, this returns a promise, meaning you wouldn't need `$q`.

```
app.factory("totalusers", function(FURL) {
    var gettotalusers = {};

    gettotalusers.getusers = function(city) {
        var tusers = new Firebase(FURL + "/Users/" + city);

        return tusers.orderByChild("Name")
                     .startAt(false)
                     .once("value")
                     .then(function(snapshot) {
            return snapshot.numChildren();
        });
    };

    return gettotalusers;
});
```

Comment: Hi @AnidMonsur, you are right, I noticed that ref.on() is gonna keep watching so I changed to ref.once(). Althought your code above is not exactly what I'm trying to do, because what I need is to check how many users who have the "Name" saved into firebase are available and count them, What your are doing is counting all of them. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Ah ok. Updated my answer for that scenario. Start at `false` because of how Firebase orders https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-ordered-data

Comment: Thanks for helping, I tried your code and it works pretty well, I just had to update to the latest Firebase version (2.4.1) cause I was having an error about the .once() having just 1 parameter, anyways, now it works perfect, thanks so much.

Comment: I just noticed that it is still counting all the users, because I tried to test it having **Name: ""** in one user into firebase but it still count all of them, I refresh the page to reload the code but it is still.

Comment: `""` is an empty string. Your original code would count that as well, since it's not `undefined`.

Comment: I changed the **startAt(false)** to **startAt(true)** and change a little my code and that was all. Thanks